# Smart Card Simulation on Ubuntu (Java Card - ISO7816) - specifying target JCRE

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, opensc

I'm trying to simulate the [OpenPGP](https://github.com/jderuiter/javacard-openpgpcard) and [IsoApplet](https://github.com/philipWendland/IsoApplet) before building and installing on a real javacard. I'd like my simulation environment to match the actual card as closely as possible.

Here are [my card specs](https://www.smartcardfocus.us/shop/ilp/id~709/javacos-a22-dual-interface-java-card-150k/p/index.shtml) from the ATR database. It follows the Java Card 2.2.2 and Global Platform 2.1.1 specifications.

I'm following the instructions on the [OpenSC GitHub to simulate a card](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Smart-Card-Simulation#compile-jcardsim-with-support-for-vpcd) with vpcsd support. These instructions end with a built `jcardsim-3.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

1. How can I build the `jcardsim` with support for virtualcard/vpcsd for version 2.2.2?
2. How do I specify the Java Card version to target when building IsoApplet with `ant-javacard`? Does my JDK impact what I can choose?

My environment is

```
Linux 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_242
```

I'm a little confused by the versioning page of the ant-javacard wiki: https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard/wiki/Version-compatibility

3. In what instances would I compile .java files using a JDK and target a different JRE version when getting class files, in order to convert to a specific JCDK version using the converter? I understand using a high JDK for better source code features, and then compiling for a specific JRE, but not when there is the additional step of targeting a JCRE.

Comment: Generally you use the correct Java Card SDK to compile for a specific platform. The SDK should have clear specifications on what JRE / compiler level to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `targetsdk` to indicate the SDK of your target platform (or anything lower than your target platform). ant-javacard sets the target class file version automatically based on the used SDK (the `jckit` parameter), which should be 3.0.5 at this point.